# Can/should production connection strings be used in type provider definitions?

Tags: f#, connection-string, type-providers

I'm just getting started with F# type providers (`SqlDataProvider`). Currently I have a production connection string in the type provider definition. The benefit of this is, of course, that one is guaranteed to always have latest version of the DB schema (as opposed to a local test database one might forget to update, potentially causing runtime exceptions when deploying).

I can also think of some reasons *not* to use a (production) connection string in the definition:

- Connection strings normally live in some app.config file (but in my case there is no such file, because I'm writing a reusable library, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580602/how-to-get-connection-string-from-head-projects-app-config-appsettings-json-in))
- Connection strings often contain sensitive data and might not be desired in code

Is it generally recommended to use production connection strings in type provider definitions?

Comment: "a local test database one might forget to update" - Deploy the latest schema to your local DB as part of the build process.

Comment: You got this right, it's not a good idea to have connection strings stored in source code, .config or not. Database schema should be a part of CI/CD, which is not trivial by itself. Yet this is the only way, really. In Jet.com it's done with MS DataTools projects deployed on dedicated sql schema server in Dev/QA environment. Your build works against this server.