# How to get connection string from head project's app.config/appsettings.json in a class library

Tags: f#, connection-string

When writing a C# class library that accesses a database, my preferred method of getting a connection string from a head project's app.config/appsettings.json is to have the DB access classes depend on some `IConnectionString` interface that is registered in an IOC container by the head project.

I am currently using F# however, and the above is not a particularly functional approach. Neither is having a static variable on a static class set by the Startup class of the head project (though it's dead simple and boilerplate-free, so that's my plan B). A complicating matter is that the head project is not F#, so that places limits on things like partial application at the top level of the program.

Is there a robust, boilerplate-free (and preferably functional) way to get a connection string from a C# head project's app.config/appsettings.json down to the instantiation of the data context in a reusable library?

Comment: For `FSharp.Data.SqlCommandProvider` you can pass in a connection string to the provided type before using it:
 `MyTypeProvidedQuery.Create(myConnString)`. Then `myConnString` is just a value that can be injected. Some code would be useful to see as this is very specific to the library that you're using (which one is it?) and it's not about type providers in general.

Comment: Package is `SqlProvider`, type provider name is `SqlDataProvider`. You're right, it's not about type providers. I'll clear up the question.